# preg_replace method in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have create preg_replace:

```
$searchTerm = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $searchTerm);
```

But when I search in search box this

```
!@#$%^&*()_+
```

it's not working.

I am expected When any one search this "!@#$%^&*()_+" then out put is "NO result Found".

Can any one suggest better preg_replace.

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Your regex will *remove anything except letter, number and space*

Comment: i am expected When any one search this "!@#$%^&*()_+" then out put is "NO result Found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to involve your regular expression with a database call, the searched value will have its content stripped of illegal characters and sent as an empty string to the database (where no results will be found):

```
$searchTerm = '!@#$%^&*()_+';
$searchTerm = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $searchTerm);

// $searchTerm = '';
// Send this off to DB (which will return false)

if (!$search->search_db($searchTerm)) {
   echo 'No search results!';
}
```

If you don't want it to touch a DB, you can just keep it within the scope of the current script:

```
if (preg_match('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', $searchTerm)) {
   echo 'No search results!';
}
```